# Can I make a page view with a contextual filter use AJAX?

Tags: views

I have a Drupal 7 view that uses an attachment to present a list of links to taxonomy terms, and use that to drive a page view, filtered on the term ID. The links in the attachment causes the page to reload. What I'd really like is a way to the page to redisplay the content when a different attachment link is clicked, without refreshing the entire page. Is there a way to use AJAX to do this?

Comment: Views can do stuff like this, but typically you would be using exposed filters, and enable ajax on the view. You can also install the Better Exposed Filters module which adds some nice functionality. Essentially your goal would be to get a relationship to those taxonomy terms and render them as filter options. There are some various views hooks you can call to alter filter options and such if you need get really crafty. In the past I've done things like render a text field filter, and then alter it to be a select with options from a query. Form API array, etc...

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I hadn't thought of doing it that way. I works, but doesn't seem much faster. What I'd like to see instead of the BEF from elements is just a simple unformatted list of text, without the radio icon. I can't figure a way to get rid of the icon, since it is a style from the web browser rather than Drupal. But it is a good technique, and I'm sure I'll have uses for it again in the future.

Comment: Remember that you can alter/preprocess the exposed filter form and change the elements after the fact. I agree it is a bit of a pain, but it the best way right now. On the positive side you have ultimate control. You could make it a select2, and render a view mode (display) inside as options. It is all possible, just start basic and work form there.